# VBA Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, vba, copy, splice

I found a macro (courtesy of Jerry Beaucaire) that splits up one worksheet into many based on unique values in a given column.  This works great.  However...

The client has supplied a differently formatted worksheet which needs some gentle massaging to get into the format we need.

First, let me show you a snippet of JB's code:

```
MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose _
    (ws.Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
```

From what I can tell (and I'm a total VB newbie, so what do I know..??), this populates an array with the selected row values

And this:

```
For Itm = 2 To UBound(MyArr)

    ...(code removed)

    ws.Range("A" & TitleRow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy _
        Sheets(MyArr(Itm) & "").Range("A1")


    ...(code removed)

Next Itm
```

...seems to do the copying.

Alright.  ...fine so far.

The problem is that I need to add a step to the process.  This will be tricky to explain.  Please bear with me...

Title row is row 1

Data starts in row 2

Each row has 9 columns:

colA: identifier

colB-colD: x,y,z values (for top of item)

colE-colG: x,y,z values (for bottom of item)

colH and colI: can be ignored

These x,y and z values are used to define points that are used to plot lines in a 3D modelling program. Each row in the worksheet actually defines a line (well... a start point and an end point - "top" and "bottom") Unfortunately, the data(worksheet) we have received defines two sets of data for each line - both having the same start point, but with different end points. Put another way, starting with rows 3 and 4, the data in columns B-D is the same for both rows.  This applies to rows 5 & 6, 7 & 8, etc.

Since all we need are a set of data POINTS, we can safely use the values from cols E-G.
HOWEVER... and this is where I need help... We need the first row of the newly created worksheet to start with the values from row 2, cols B-D. (ie. we can use the end points as our coordinates, but we still need the first start point)  All the rest is fine the way it is.

For example:

Source Data:

```
   | A  |   B   |   C   |   D   |     E    |     F    |     G    |
 1 | id | x-top | y-top | z-top | x-bottom | y-bottom | z-bottom |
 2 | H1 | 101.2 | 0.525 | 54.25 |  110.25  |  0.625   |  56.75   |
 3 | H1 | 110.25| 0.625 | 56.75 |  121.35  |  2.125   |  62.65   |
 4 | H1 | 110.25| 0.625 | 56.75 |  134.85  |  3.725   |  64.125  |  B,C,D same as row 3
 5 | H1 | 134.85| 3.725 | 64.125|  141.25  |  4.225   |  66.75   |
 6 | H1 | 134.85| 3.725 | 64.125|  148.85  |  5.355   |  69.85   |  B,C,D same as row 5
```

What I need:

```
   | A  |   B   |   C   |   D   |     E    |     F    |     G    |
 1 | id | x-top | y-top | z-top | x-bottom | y-bottom | z-bottom |
 2 | H1 |       |       |       |  101.2   |  0.525   |  54.25   |
 3 | H1 | 101.2 | 0.525 | 54.25 |  110.25  |  0.625   |  56.75   |
 4 | H1 | 110.25| 0.625 | 56.75 |  121.35  |  2.125   |  62.65   |
 5 | H1 | 110.25| 0.625 | 56.75 |  134.85  |  3.725   |  64.125  |
 6 | H1 | 134.85| 3.725 | 64.125|  141.25  |  4.225   |  66.75   |
 7 | H1 | 134.85| 3.725 | 64.125|  148.85  |  5.355   |  69.85   |
```

So...  What's the best way to do this?  Can I add to the existing macro to perform this operation?  If so, better to modify the array? ...better to modify the Copy routine?  ...and how??

Thanks in advance for your help and please don't suggest doing it manually.  There are 70,000+ rows to parse!

If you need more info, let me know!

Comment: Can you confirm that all you need is to insert a row after the header row and shift the values from B-D to E-G?

Comment: "From what I can tell (and I'm a total VB newbie, so what do I know..??)" Set a breakpoint on that line, set a watch on that array, and step through your code in debug mode. Then you will know.

Comment: Yes, Rachel, I need to insert a data row after the header row. The data that would then be in row 3 (the first data row with values - having moved from row 2 due to the insertion) columns B-D, should be copied to row 2 (the new, blank row) columns E-G.

Since VB is still Greek to me, I'm just not sure if it would be easier to do this when the arrays are built, after they are built (but before the new worksheets are created) or after the data has been added to the new worksheet.

...oh, right... AND how to do it. ;)

Comment: Jean-Francois,

Since the macro that I found, does what it's supposed to, and since it is quite light on code, I was able to decipher what was happening where.  I'm pretty confident that that is what that code does (building the array).  I included that bit because I thought I should provide some brief background as to what I was trying to do and how I was doing it.

...that being said, I will keep your suggestion in mind for any future VB development I may have to do. Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm new here, can someone please tell me why my post indicates it has been edited by someone else?  Did I screw something up?  I just don't wanna step on the toes of anybody who might be trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The full macro is available for free to all at [this location](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/parse-functions/sheet1-to-sheets)

To achieve your connecting points, these additions should do it:

```
For Itm = 2 To UBound(MyArr)

    ...(code removed)

    ws.Range("A" & TitleRow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy _
      Sheets(MyArr(Itm) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(MyArr(Itm) & "").Rows(2).Insert xlShiftDown
    Sheets(MyArr(Itm) & "").Range("E2").Resize(, 3).Value = Sheets(MyArr(Itm) & "").Range("B3").Resize(, 3).Value

    ...(code removed)

Next Itm
```